# Accessing a subclass property from a super class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to programming and need some help with inheritance in Swift. I am creating a cart-type app for creating quotes in my business. I have a product class with a sub-class for specific product types so I can give them custom properties. I have a cart class where i can pass in the product class and qty required.

My question is, once I have created the product and passed it into the cart I want to access a property in my subclass, but I can not work out how to make that happen. Help Please? This is my code.

My Product Class

```
class ProductItem: NSObject {

var productCode:String!
var productDescription:String!
var manufacturerListPrice:Double!
}
```

Product sub-class

```
class DigitalHandset: ProductItem {

var digitalPortsRequired:Int!

init(productCode: String, listPrice: Double){
    super.init()
    super.productCode = productCode
    super.manufacturerListPrice = listPrice
    super.productDescription = ""

    self.digitalPortsRequired = 1
    }
}
```

Cart Class

```
public class bomItems: NSObject {

    var quantity:Int
    var productItem:ProductItem

    init(product: ProductItem, quantity: Int) {
        self.productItem = product
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
class testModelCode{
    var system = MasterSystem() // This class holds my array of cart items (BOM or Bill Of Materials) 
    var bomItem1 = bomItems(product: DigitalHandset(productCode: "NEC999", listPrice: 899), quantity: 8)

func addToSystem() {
    system.billOfMaterials.append(bomItem1) //I have a system class that holds an array for the cart items.
    //At this point I want to access a property of the Digital Handset class but it appears that I can not. 
    //Can anyone point me in the right direction to allow this. 
    //The following is what is not working. 
    bomItem2.DigitalHandset.digitalPortsRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `bomItem2` is of type `ProductItem`, you need to downcast it to type `DigitalHandset` in order to access the properties of `DigitalHandset`.  The safe way to do this is to use a conditional downcast `as?` along with optional binding `if let` syntax:

```
if let digitalHandset = bomItem2 as? DigitalHandset {
    // if we get here, bomItem2 is indeed a DigitalHandset
    let portsRequired = digitalHandset.portsRequired
} else {
    // bomItem2 is something other than a DigitalHandset
}
```

If you will be checking many classes, the `switch` statement comes in handy:

```
switch bomItem2 {
case digitalHandset as DigitalHandset:
    println("portsRequired is \(digitalHandset.portsRequired)")
case appleWatch as AppleWatch:
    println("type of Apple Watch is \(appleWatch.type)")
default:
    println("hmmm, some other type")
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank-you very much. I had played around with downcast but could not get it to work, your solution worked perfectly. Thanks!